# Do we say "lean the broom in the corner of the wall and the wardrobe" or "lean the broom in the corner between the wall and the wardrobe"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

> [cor‧ner](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/corner) 1 /ˈkɔːnə $ ˈkɔːrnər/ ●●● S1 W2 noun
>
> 1 WHERE TWO LINES/EDGES MEET [countable] the point at which two lines
> or edges meet
>
> He pulled a dirty handkerchief out by its corner and waved it at me.
>
> corner of  Their initials were sewn on the corner of every pillow.
>
> in the corner (of something)  The TV station’s name appears in the
> corner of the screen.
>
> on the corner (of something)  Jessie sat on the corner of her bed.
>
> three-cornered/four-cornered etc  a three-cornered hat

Normally, dictionaries often say "**the corner of a thing**", for example, "**the corner of the room**". However, there are corners that are formed by **2 or 3 things**. Then, how are we going to express it, for example, "**the corner of the wall and the wardrobe**" or "**the corner between the wall and the wardrobe**"?

Do we say "**lean the broom in the corner of the wall and the wardrobe**" or "**lean the broom in the corner between the wall and the wardrobe**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying “in the corner of the wall and the wardrobe” sounds wrong to me; generally speaking I think a corner should be said to belong only to one thing.

While much better, in my opinion, I also think that “in the corner between the wall and the wardrobe” could be confusing, as I might find myself looking for a corner *of the room* between a wall and a wardrobe. However, if this description were accompanied by someone pointing and phrasing it as “this/that corner” instead of “the corner” I think any confusion would be removed.

I think something like the following would be appropriate:

> Lean it between the wall and the wardrobe.

> Rest it between the wall and the wardrobe.

Comment: "In this/that corner" is a good choice. But, what about "the corner where the wardrobe meets the wall"

Comment: That would also be fine, although very mildly theatrical/amusing to my ears. Again, though, I don’t think you’d need to describe it as a corner, “where the wardrobe meets the wall” would be sufficient.